# How can I filter a data frame with a datetime index by a month and year input? Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

Given a `df` like this:

```
df=pd.read_csv(PATH + 'Matriz3_fechas.csv',index_col='Fecha',skiprows=0)
df.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(df.index)
```

Note that Fecha is already the index with datetime format**

```
 Fecha                D576972dc305aa  D576972dc32e9a  D576972dc3590a  
                                                             
2016-06-01 00:00:00         0.0          0.0               0.1  
2016-07-01 00:05:00         0.0          0.0               0.1  
2017-05-01 00:10:00         0.0          0.0               0.1  
2017-05-01 00:15:00         0.0          0.0               0.1                                                              
2017-07-01 00:20:00         0.0          0.0               0.1
```

I´ve tried to filter by month and year:

```
df=df[(df.index.month==5)&(matriz.index.year==2017)]
```

But it wont filter the `df` to get: (desired result)

```
 Fecha                D576972dc305aa  D576972dc32e9a  D576972dc3590a  \
                                                             
2017-05-01 00:10:00         0.0          0.0               0.1  \
2017-05-01 00:15:00         0.0          0.0               0.1  \
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [partial string indexing](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#partial-string-indexing):

```
#for datetimeindex use parameter parse_dates 
df=pd.read_csv(PATH+'Matriz3_fechas.csv',index_col='Fecha',skiprows=0,parse_dates=['Fecha'])

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2016-06-01 00:00:00', '2016-07-01 00:05:00',
               '2017-05-01 00:10:00', '2017-05-01 00:15:00',
               '2017-07-01 00:20:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Fecha', freq=None)


df = df.loc['2017-05']
print (df)
                     D576972dc305aa  D576972dc32e9a  D576972dc3590a
Fecha                                                              
2017-05-01 00:10:00             0.0             0.0             0.1
2017-05-01 00:15:00             0.0             0.0             0.1
```

But your solution also works (if `matriz` is `df`, I think typo):

```
df=df[(df.index.month==5)&(df.index.year==2017)]
print (df)
                     D576972dc305aa  D576972dc32e9a  D576972dc3590a
Fecha                                                              
2017-05-01 00:10:00             0.0             0.0             0.1
2017-05-01 00:15:00             0.0             0.0             0.1
```

Comment: It was so simple

Comment: So `print (df.index)` return `DatetimeIndex`? months with days are not swapped?

Comment: I had tried that before but the shape of the output i get its [0 rows x 3 columns] instead of [2 rows x 3 columns] @jezrael

Comment: Hmmm, it means there are no data with `2017` and `5` month. But maybe `2017-05-10` is swapped to `2017-10-05` so it filter wrong. can you check it?

Comment: @jezreal Found out the problem, my .csv was not updated so it did not have data from 2017-05. Nevertheless your answer helped me.